# Reference for a proof of a projective representation of $A_6$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, projective-geometry

This question is copied from math.stackexchange, in hope that it might get some attension.

I want to understand the proof of

> There is a projective representation of $A_6 \hookrightarrow PSU(3).$

I am looking for a reference, but could not find. Suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: We have a central extension: $$0 \to C_3 \hookrightarrow \hat{A}_6 \twoheadrightarrow A_6 \to 0. $$ From a result of Schur, the determining the projective representation reduces to determining a linear representation from the central group extension $$\hat{A}_6 \to SU(3).$$ Now I don't know what the next step should be.

A reference will be very helpful to me.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentiner_group

Comment: The existence of this representation has been known for over 100 years, and it might be hard to find good modern references. Of course an easy way to prove the existence is just to write down matrices corresponding to generators of $3.A_6$. All complex representations of finite groups preserve a unitary form, so that aspect is not an issue.

Comment: This is often known as the Valentiner group. Fairly explicit information can be found in ( for example) http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-01/S0002-9939-04-07539-2/S0002-9939-04-07539-2.pdf

Comment: This paper also seems useful here: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1047262404